# how to add picker and in picker item user button instead values

Tags: react-native, picker

i want to add picker on image when i click on it open picker with two button when i select anyone desire screen open please help me with this
here is the code i want to replace picker with touchableopacity

```
 <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.cameraUpload()}
        style={styles.buttonStyle}
      >
        <Image
          style={styles.buttonImageStyle}
          source={require("../../../android/app/src/main/assets/images/uploadImage.png")}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: You need to provide more insight. What does your picker code look like, update your question with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the `value` of the `picker` as a status value and replace the `image` with a corresponding change.

```js
        <Picker
          style={styles.picker} itemStyle={styles.pickerItem}
          selectedValue={this.state.image}
          onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({image: itemValue})}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="image1" value="../../../android/app/src/main/assets/images/uploadImage.png" />
          <Picker.Item label="image2" value="../../../android/app/src/main/assets/images/uploadImage2.png" />
          <Picker.Item label="image3" value="../../../android/app/src/main/assets/images/uploadImage3.png" />
          <Picker.Item label="image4" value="../../../android/app/src/main/assets/images/uploadImage4.png" />
        </Picker>
...
       <Image
          style={styles.buttonImageStyle}
          source={require(this.state.image)}
        />
```